# Issue copying files from GCP to S3 using gsutil

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

When trying to copy files from a google bucket to an s3 bucket, using the following command:

```
gsutil -m rsync -rd gs://est s3://test/test
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Building synchronization state...
Caught non-retryable exception while listing s3://test/test: AccessDeniedException: 403 None
CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
```

I think everything is set up correctly. I have created the boto file, and added in the as key & secret key. I have added the auth rules for the region (eu-west-2) for v4. The only way I can get the copy to work is to setup an s3 bucket which is an old auth v2 region.

I cannot find anywhere what '403 None' could mean. It suggest to me that there isn't actually an error? But nothing is being copied.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: 403 means Permission Denied. You have not correctly configured the AWS keys correctly with `gsutil`.

Comment: @JohnHanley - I don't think this is correct. I have managed to get it working by removing the -rd, and removing the /test sub folder. I can copy the files to the root directory just fine.

Comment: Yo can check what request exactly gets error by running gsutil with `-D` flag. Please post the error output. My guess is that due to [rsync -d flag](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#options_1) it tries to delete some files you don't have access to.